# How does one correctly store data into an array struct with stringstream?

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, io, stringstream

I was wondering how to store data from a CSV file into a structured array. I realize I need to use getline and such and so far I have come up with this code:

This is my struct:

```
struct csvData //creating a structure
{
     string username; //creating a vector of strings called username
     float gpa; //creating a vector of floats called gpa
     int age; //creating a vector of ints called age
};
```

This is my data reader and the part that stores the data:

```
csvData arrayData[10];
string data;
ifstream infile; //creating object with ifstream
infile.open("datafile.csv"); //opening file
if (infile.is_open()) //error check

int i=0;
while(getline(infile, data));
{
    stringstream ss(data);
    ss >> arrayData[i].username;
    ss >> arrayData[i].gpa;
    ss >> arrayData[i].age;
    i++;
}
```

Further, this is how I was attempting to print out the information:

```
for (int z = 0; z<10; z++)
    {
        cout<<arrayData[z].username<<arrayData[z].gpa<<arrayData[z].age<<endl;
    }
```

However, when running this command, I get a cout of what seem to be random numbers:

1.83751e-0383 03 4.2039e-0453 1.8368e-0383 07011688

I assume this has to be the array running not storing the variables correctly and thus I am reading out random memory slots, however, I am unsure.

Lastly, here is the CSV file I am attempting to read.

```
username,gpa,age
Steven,3.2,20
Will,3.4,19
Ryan,3.6,19
Tom,3,19
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in your parsing code that actually attempts to parse the single line into the individual fields:

```
while(getline(infile, data));
{
```

This correctly reads a single line from the input file into the `data` string.

```
 stringstream ss(data);

 ss >> arrayData[i].username;
 ss >> arrayData[i].gpa;
 ss >> arrayData[i].age;
```

You need to try [to explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how this is supposed to take a single line of comma-separated values, like the one you showed in your question:

```
 Steven,3.2,20
```

and separate that string into the individual values, by commas. There's nothing about the `>>` operator that will do this. `operator>>` separates input using whitespaces, not commas. Your suspicions were correct, you were not parsing the input correctly.

This is a task that you have to do yourself. I am presuming that you would like, as a learning experience, or as a homework assignment, to do this yourself, manually. Well, then, do it yourself. You have the a single line in `data`. Use any number of tools that C++ gives you: the `std::string`'s `find()` method, or `std::find`() from `<algorithm>`, to find each comma in the `data` string, then extract each individual portion of the string that's between each comma. Then, you still need to convert the two numeric fields into the appropriate datatypes. And that's when you put each one of them into a `std::istringstream`, and use `operator>>` to convert them to numeric types.

But, having said all that, there's an alternative dirty trick, to solve this problem quickly. Recall that the original line in `data` contains

```
 Steven,3.2,20
```

All you have to do is replace the commas with spaces, turning it into:

```
 Steven 3.2 20
```

Replacing commas with spaces is trivial with `std::replace()`, or with a small loop. Then, you can stuff the result into a `std::istringstream`, and use `operator>>` to extract the individual whitespace-delimited values into the discrete variables, using the code that you've already written.

Just a small word of warning: if this was indeed your homework assignment, to write code to manually parse and extract comma-delimited values, it's not guaranteed that your instructor will give you the full grade for taking the dirty-trick approach...

Comment: I've been trying, however I keep getting stuck trying to parse the first string. Why doesn't this work:   while(getline(infile,data, ','))

Comment: Because not every value in the file is followed by a comma character. Every third value is followed by a newline character. That's why you have multiple lines in the file. You see, a program does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do. You told it to read until the next comma character. So that's what it's going to do. If it sees a newline, your program will not care much, it's told to read until it sees a comma, so it'll keep reading until it sees the comma on the next line, squishing everything together with the last value from the previous line, as one string.

Comment: Hey man, I am having quite a lot of trouble trying to parse the data file. Is there any way you could give me a hint of some sample code to go off of? I've been stuck for 5 days now...

Comment: My answer already gives two different ways to parse the file. One of them requires only one more line of code added to the code you already wrote and included in the question. You need to reread my answer.

Answer (score 2):

UNDER CONSTRUCTION

Ton, nice try and nice complete question. Here is the answer:

1) You have a semicolon after the loop:

```
while(getline(infile, data));
```

delete it.

How did I figure that out easily? I compiled with all the warnings enabled, like this:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp:24:33: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
    while(getline(infile, data));
                                ^
main.cpp:24:33: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning generated.
```

In fact, you should get that warning without `-Wall` as well, but get into using it, it will also make good to you! :)

2) Then, you read some elements, but not 10, so why do you print 10? Print as many as the ones you actually read, i.e. `i`.

When you try to print all 10 elements of your array, you print elements that are not initialized, since you didn't initialize your array of structs.

Moreover, the number of lines in `datafile.csv` was less than 10. So you started populating your array, but you stopped, when the file didn't have more lines. As a result, some of the elements of your array (the last 6 elements) remained uninitialized.

Printing uninitialized data, causes **Undefined Behavior**, that's why you see garbage values.

3) Also this:

```
if (infile.is_open()) //error check
```

could be written like this:

```
if (!infile.is_open())
  cerr << "Error Message by Mr. Tom\n";
```

---

Putting them all together:

WILL STILL NOT WORK, BECAUSE `ss >> arrayData[i].username;` eats the entire input line and the next two extractions fail, as Pete Becker said, but I leave it here, so that others won't make the same attempt!!!!!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct csvData //creating a structure
{
     string username; //creating a vector of strings called username
     float gpa; //creating a vector of floats called gpa
     int age; //creating a vector of ints called age
};

int main()
{
    csvData arrayData[10];
    string data;
    ifstream infile; //creating object with ifstream
    infile.open("datafile.csv"); //opening file
    if (!infile.is_open()) { cerr << "File is not opened..\n"; }

    int i=0;
    while(getline(infile, data))
    {
        stringstream ss(data);
        ss >> arrayData[i].username;
        ss >> arrayData[i].gpa;
        ss >> arrayData[i].age;
        i++;
    }

    for (int z = 0; z< i; z++)
    {
        cout<<arrayData[z].username<<arrayData[z].gpa<<arrayData[z].age<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
username,gpa,age00
Steven,3.2,2000
Will,3.4,1900
Ryan,3.6,1900
Tom,3,1900
```

---

But wait a minute, so now it works, but why this:

```
while(getline(infile, data));
{
   ...
}
```

didn't?

Because, putting a semicolon after a loop is equivalent to this:

```
while()
{ 
  ;
}
```

because as you probably already know loops with only one line as a body do not require curly brackets.

And what happened to what I thought it was the body of the loop (i.e. the part were you use `std::stringstream`)?

It got executed! **But only once!**.

You see, a pair of curly brackets alone means something, it's an anonymous scope/block.

So this:

```
{
    stringstream ss(data);
    ss >> arrayData[i].username;
    ss >> arrayData[i].gpa;
    ss >> arrayData[i].age;
    i++;
}
```

functioned on its one, without being part of the while loop, as you intended too!

Any why did it work?! Because you had declared `i` before the loop! ;)

Comment: This doesn't address the core problem, which is that `ss >> arrayData[i].username;` eats the entire input line and the next two extractions fail.

Comment: @PeteBecker damn, missed that by far! Thanks, the printing didn't help. Any ideas on it?